# Is it possible for the pressure gradient to vary while the density remains a constant along a streamline of an incompressible fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Given an incompressible and inviscid fluid with constant temperature, is it possible for the pressure gradient to vary while the density remains a constant along a streamline? Can I assume that the density change is negligible under any influence of pressure in any incompressble fluid?

Comment: For an incompressible fluid, the density is independent of pressure.  This is the definition of an incompressible fluid.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, sure.

You can use [Bernoulli's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation) for imcompressible flow.

For this derivation, you assume density remains constant, while pressure changes may be significant.

> Can I assume that the density change is negligible under any influence of pressure in any incompressble fluid?

*Sort of*.  The density is never truly invariant with pressure.  For many liquids (like water for example), the change in density relative to change in pressure is quite small.  For most situations, assuming that the density isn't changed by pressure will not create an appreciable error.

That doesn't mean you should *always* assume that for liquids that are "incompressible" under normal conditions.  If you are working with high pressures and data that is sensitive to small errors, it may not be good to assume the fluid is incompressible.

If you're already working under the assumption that the fluid *is* incompressible; then yes, you assume the density change is negligible under any influence of pressure, because that is the definition of an incompressible fluid.